# Ruby : How to remove duplicate lines from a document text?

Tags: ruby, line

I want to remove duplicate lines from a text for example :

```
1.aabba
2.abaab
3.aabba
4.aabba
```

After running :

```
1.aabba
2.abaab
```

Tried so far :

```
lines = File.readlines("input.txt")
lines = File.read('/path/to/file')
lines.split("\n").uniq.join("\n")
```

Comment: Please include the code you have tried so far

Comment: i have edited the code

Comment: It's not clear whether the leading line numbers are part of the text or are there merely for illustration.

Comment: Ah, but it wasn't too late prior to answering a question that wasn't asked well. Remember, "[answer]" says we  "Answer well-asked questions". :-)

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and its linked pages. Clarity is important for us to help you.

Comment: Your code suggests that the first line is actually `'aabba'`, not `'1.aabba'`, in which case you should not have included the line numbers. At least two answers assume the line numbers are not there, but at least one answer assumes that they are. It's too late to edit your question to either change the data or explain what is intended, as would make at least one answer nonsensical. Also, your code suggests you want to write the unique lines to another file, but you have not said that. Lastly, your example is unnecessarily hard to follow because of all the permutations of `'a'` and `'b'`.

Answer (score 3):

Let's construct a file.

```
fname = 't'

IO.write fname, <<~END
dog
cat
dog
pig
cat
END
  #=> 20
```

See [IO::write](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-write). First let's suppose you simply want to read the unique lines into an array.

If, as here, the file is not excessive large, you can write:

```
arr = IO.readlines(fname, chomp: true).uniq
  #=> ["dog", "cat", "pig"]
```

See [IO::readlines](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-readlines). `chomp: true` removes the newline character at the end of each line.

If you wish to then write that array to another file:

```
fname_out = 'tt'
IO.write(fname_out, arr.join("\n") << "\n")
  #=> 12
```

or

```
File.open(fname_out, 'w') do |f|
  arr.each { |line| f.puts line }
end
```

If you wish to overwrite `fname`, write to a new file, delete the existing file and then rename the new file `fname`.

If the file is so large it cannot be held in memory *and* there are many duplicate lines, you might be able to do the following.

```
require 'set'

st = IO.foreach(fname, chomp: true).with_object(Set.new) do |line, st|
  st.add(line)
end
  #=> #<Set: {"dog", "cat", "pig"}>
```

See [IO::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach).

If you wish to simply write the contents of this set to file, you can execute:

```
File.open(fname_out, 'w') do |f|
  st.each { |s| f.puts(s) }
end
```

If instead you need to convert the set to an array:

```
st.to_a
  #=> ["dog", "cat", "pig"]
```

This assumes you have enough memory to hold both `st` and `st.to_a`. If not, you could write:

```
st.size.times.with_object([]) do |_,a|
  s = st.first
  a << s
  st.delete(s)
end
  #=> ["dog", "cat", "pig"]
```

If you don't have enough memory to even hold `st` you will need to read your file (line-by-line) into a database and then use database operations.

If you wish to write the file with the duplicates skipped, and the file is very large, you may do the following, albeit with the infinitesimal risk of including one or more duplicates (see the comments).

```
require 'set'

line_map = IO.foreach(fname, chomp: true).with_object({}) do |line,h|
  hsh = line.hash
  h[hsh] = $. unless h.key?(hsh)
end
  #=> {3393575068349183629=>1, -4358860729541388342=>2,
  #    -176447925574512206=>4}
```

[$.](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/variable.html) is the number (base 1) of the line just read. See [String#hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-hash). Since the number of distinct values returned by this method is finite and the number of possible strings is infinite, there is the possibility that two distinct strings could have the same hash value.

Then (assuming `line_map` is not empty):

```
lines_to_keep = line_map.values 
File.open(fname_out, 'w') do |fout|
  IO.foreach(fname, chomp: true) do |line|
    if lines_to_keep.first == $.
      fout.puts(line)
      lines_to_keep.shift
    end
  end
end
```

Let's see what we've written:

```
puts File.read(fname_out)
dog
cat
pig
```

See [File::open](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/File.html#method-c-open).

Incidentally, for `IO` class methods `m` (including `read`, `write`, `readlines` and `foreach`), you may see `IO.m...` written `File.m...`. That's permissible because `File` is a subclass of `IO` and therefore inherits the latter's methods. That does not apply to my use of `File::open`, as [IO::Open](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-open) is a different method.

Comment: Another tip: If the lines are really big, use a `Set` but hash each line (e.g. SHA2-256) to avoid having to store the whole line.

Comment: @tadman, thanks for the suggestion. I've edited my answer to cover it. I actually had considered including it before but decided not to because of the possibility of a duplicated line being repeated. In situations like this I always think of that because my one and only commercial programming task was writing a computer backup program that operated over telephone lines (and later, the internet). To avoid transferring files already in our *library* I computed something like a hash code for each new or changed file at the user's end and then checked them against our server's database.

Comment: Yeah, this is like implementing a very basic version of what `rsync` does internally. It's amazing what you can do with a few hashes and a look-up table.

Answer (score 2):

`Set` only stores unique elements, so:

```
require 'Set'

s = Set.new
while line = gets
  s << line.strip
end
s.each { |unique_elt| puts unique_elt }
```

You can run this with any input file using `< input.txt` on the command-line rather than hardwiring the file name into your program.

Note that `Set` is based on `Hash`, and the documentation states "Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys were inserted", so this will preserve the order of entry.

Answer (score 0):

You can continue your idea with `uniq`.

[`uniq`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-uniq) compares result of the block and delete duplicates.

For example you have `input.txt` with this content:

```
1.aabba
2.abaab
3.aabba
4.aabba
```

```
puts File.readlines('input.txt', chomp: true).
  uniq { |line| line.sub(/\A\d+\./, '') }.
  join("\n")

# will print
# 1.aabba
# 2.abaab
```

Here [`Sring#sub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-sub) that delete list numbers, but you can use other methods, for example `line[2..-1]`.